# sinon spy testing onClick react component with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I am using to `sinon` to test a react component to confirm that a function is triggered `onClick`.

I am using `styled-components` so finding it difficult to target the element to click on.

I am seeing the following error:

> Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

My react code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Button extends Component {

  pressNumber = () => {
    this.props.updateNumber(this.props.number)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <ButtonContainer 
        onClick={ this.pressNumber }
      >
        <Number>{ this.props.number }</Number>
      </ButtonContainer>
    )
  }

}

const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
`

const Number = styled.div`
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
`
```

My test then looks like this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import React from 'react'
import Button from './index'

describe('Button', () => {

  let wrapper
  const pressNumber = () => {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Button 
        number={1} 
        pressNumber={ pressNumber } 
      />
    )
  })

  it('should call the update pin prop when click is simulated', () => {
    const updatePinClick = sinon.spy();
    wrapper.find('ButtonContainer').simulate('click')
    expect(updatePinClick.calledOnce).to.be.true
  })

})
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here, and if there is a different approach as I am using styled-components.

I am seeing the following error

> Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(disclosure: i'm an enzyme maintainer)

Your spy is `updatePinClick`, but you're not passing it anywhere, so it can't be used. Additionally, `Button` doesn't take a `pressNumber` prop.

First, I'd suggest the following general tips:

1. Avoid `.simulate` - if you want to invoke a prop, do it directly, like `.prop('onClick')()`.
2. Don't define the wrapper in a `beforeEach` - in tests, it's far better to repeat yourself, and specifically the jsx you're using.
3. Avoid passing strings into `.find`; it's less brittle to export the component you want to find, and find it by reference instead.
4. Avoid noop matchers - ie, things that don't end in a function, like `.to.be.true`. This is because you could easily make a typo and it would fail silently - `expect(object).to.be.yogurt;` will happily pass, even though that's not a valid matcher.
5. Prefer `shallow` for all your tests. Only use `mount` when it's necessary to use refs, or to test `componentDidMount`, or other browser-only code.

Specifically, try this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import React from 'react'
import Button from './index'

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should call the update pin prop when click is simulated', () => {
    const updatePinClick = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Button 
        number={1} 
        updateNumber={updatePinClick} 
      />
    );
    wrapper.find('ButtonContainer').prop('onClick')();
    expect(updatePinClick).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
    expect(updatePinClick.calledWith(1)).to.equal(true);
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm curious about your first point as [Enzyme's own docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) recommend `.simulate`

Comment: They certainly document it; if you can point me to where it’s recommended I’ll be happy to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* probably follow LJHarb's advice, however to simply address the error:

> Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found
>   instead.

Using `mount` to render your `<Button/>` will render it *and* all it's children (and their children, and so on). As a result, `<ButtonContainer/>` and `<Number/>` have been rendered into `<div>`s. Thus searching for `ButtonContainer` yields 0 results found.

Comment: The tree that `mount` produces contains both host nodes (DOM nodes) and React components, so it should indeed locate `ButtonContainer`.

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. Can you help explain why it couldn't find `ButtonContainer`?

Comment: Presumably because it was being found by string, which uses the displayName - and there’s no way for styled-components to have known that the template tag was assigned to a variable named “ButtonContainer”. Try using `.debug()` to see what’s really in the tree.